# Filter over queryset with a loop

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have inital queryset and I loop over this

```
stats = {}
queryset = Item.objects.all()
for sub in Subject.objects.all():
        stats[str(sub.id)] = queryset.filter(subjects=sub.id).count()
```

How I can do this without to hit the DB so often?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for [django aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Count

stats = Subject.objects.annotate(count=Count('item'))
```

Now each stats object will have `count` field:

```
stats[0].count
```

Comment: This solution is better for your case, use `values()` when you need a different grouping.

Answer (score 3):

```
Subject.objects.values('pk').annotate(total=Count('item'))
```